# Insert values into database from visual studio c++ 2010 with values from keyboard...?

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

OK..so now i've got this code:

```
namespace testtesttest {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Data;

class Forme
{
    string name;
public:

    Forme( char *_name ) : name(_name)
    {
    }

    ~Forme()
    {
    }

    void save()
    {

        String^ constring = L"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
        MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection( constring );

        string temp(MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand( " insert into test.first (NAME) values ('"+this->name+"');" ) );
        String^ myInter = gcnew String( temp.c_str() );
        MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand(myInter, conDataBase);

        MySqlDataReader^ myReader;

        try{
            conDataBase->Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();

            cout << endl << "SAVE!";

            while( myReader->Read() )
            {

            }
            } catch( Exception^ex) {
                                   }

    }
};
};
```

...and i get this:

> 1>testtesttest.cpp(34): error C2587: 'this' : illegal use of local variable as default parameter
>
> 1>          testtesttest.cpp(29) : see declaration of 'this'
>
> 1>testtesttest.cpp(34): error C2227: left of '->name' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
>
> 1>testtesttest.cpp(35): error C2228: left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union
>
> 1>
>
> 1>Build FAILED.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get your error in this line:

```
MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand( " insert into test.first (NAME) values ('"+this->name+"');", conDataBase );
```

Using c-style strings, you cannot concatenate them using `+`. Instead you need to use a function like `strcat` or `sprintf`.

```
char temp[300];
sprintf(temp, " insert into test.first (NAME) values ('%s');", this->name);
MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand(temp, conDataBase);
```

It's usually safer and easier to use C++ style strings for that:

```
class Forme
{
    std::string name;
public:
    Forme( char *_name ) : name(_name)
    {
    }

void save( )
    {
       ...
       std::string temp(" insert into test.first (NAME) values ('"+this->name+"');");
       MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand(temp.c_str(), conDataBase);
       ...
    }
```

**EDIT:**
For your follow up problem:
This was actually an error on my post. I corrected it.

Comment: Then you need to convert char* to String^ to make it work. Without seeing the code for `MySqlCommand` it is difficult to know this would happen.

Comment: when i try to convert, i get this : 'this' : illegal use of local variable as default parameter
1>          testtesttest.cpp(68) : see declaration of 'this'
1>testtesttest.cpp(73): error C2227: left of '->name' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>testtesttest.cpp(74): error C2228: left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union...the code is string temp(MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand( " insert into test.first (NAME) values ('"+this->name+"');" ) );
   String^ myInter = gcnew String( temp.c_str() );
 MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand(myInter, conDataBase);

Comment: Sorry, I cannot read that in a good way. Pls edit into your question, or create a new one

Answer (score 0):

Try using cmd instead of cmdDataBase.
And add the following "using namespace MySql::Data::MySqlClient;"
If you are coding in visual studio 10 and above and with mysql 5.6 and above